# Duplicate webview instances in developer tools on newer Android versions

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools, android-webview

Our app by default have two webviews: one shows hosted locally page with some web logic, another one not seen by user and used sometimes to send GET requests with cached cookies. On device with Android 11 in Chrome Dev tools shown only the first one, which is ok, but when the app runs on device with Android 13 both webviews are present (not a problem) and what's weirder each one have two similar instances (please see screenshots).
Both are instances of customized WebView subclass without any specific logic for any Android version.

So, is it possible to disable duplication or at least what is the cause?

[image: Android 11 dev tools]

[image: Android 13 dev tools]

Comment: No, as we soon found out that this really not a problem for us and real cause somewhere else.